# Stored Procedure If / Then Statement

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

We are trying to implement a password interval, if there is one.

If sm_Setting(PasswordExpireDays) has a value, we use it. If not, continue on

```
CREATE Procedure user_password_date_interval_check
    @ua_pk uniqueidentifier
AS
    DECLARE @PasswordExpireDays int
    SET @PasswordExpireDays = 0

    SELECT
        sm_Setting, sm_Value
    FROM
        Setting_Misc AS sm
    INNER JOIN
        Syndicates As syn ON sm.syn_fk = syn.syn_pk
    INNER JOIN
        Company As c ON c.syn_fk = syn.syn_pk
    INNER JOIN
        User_Accounts As ua ON ua.c_fk = c.c_pk
    WHERE 
        sm.sm_Setting = 'PasswordExpireDays'
        THEN sm.sm_Value = @PasswordExpireDays
```

I'm having issues with the `WHERE` clause. I have tried `CASE`. Bottom line is, this row (based on a PK and Setting), I want to grab the value from the `Value` column.

Comment: you need an `update`

Comment: okay, where?  i'm kinda rusty at SQL

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: okay, so a i have a table (Settings) that has a lot of information.  It's a misc table.  So I'm looking for "PasswordExpireDays' in the column.  If that's the case, I want the numerical value of the Value Column in the same row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE Procedure user_password_date_interval_check
    @ua_pk uniqueidentifier
AS
    DECLARE @PasswordExpireDays int

    SELECT
      --sm_Setting, 
      @PasswordExpireDays =COALESCE(sm_Value,0)

    FROM
      Setting_Misc AS sm
    INNER JOIN
      Syndicates As syn 
      ON sm.syn_fk = syn.syn_pk
    INNER JOIN
      Company As c
      ON c.syn_fk = syn.syn_pk
    INNER JOIN
      User_Accounts As ua
      ON ua.c_fk = c.c_pk

    WHERE sm.sm_Setting = 'PasswordExpireDays'


    --@PasswordExpireDays is either default 0 or the value from the table if not null.
```

Comment: You cannot do this `sm_Setting, @PasswordExpireDays =COALESCE(sm_Value,0)`

Comment: It's throwing an error.  I could try to put that under SET

Comment: Because you will get this error **A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.**

Comment: Cannot set a data-retrieval in a SELECT (or something like that)

Comment: So, quick questions.  If "PasswordExpireDays' does not show in that row, it should retrieve nothing, correct?  and this is will place the value of sm_Value into @PasswordExpireDays so I can use it later, correct?

Comment: If sm_Value does not have a value for that setting (a null) or no record exists in the table then COALSECE will force @PasswordExpireDays to whatever you supply as the second formal parameter, in the example above, 0. You can then examine the value of the variable and even return it from your stored procedure after the query executes.

Comment: Sounds exactly like what I need.  Thank you.  I haven't done SQL for awhile.  I appreciate it

Comment: I'm glad that I could help.